# How can I minimize negative impact on GC if I unable to provide experience letter for few years in my Career?

Tags: usa, greencard

I am working in USA with H1B VISA and pursuing for Employment based Green Card. I came to know that experience letters are required. I have totally 10 years of experiance. I got experience letter for most of my employers till past 8 years. How ever the first organization where I have worked for 2 years that I worked was closed and I am not able to reach any one from management of that organization. Hence my question is

If I unable to get the experience letter for those 2 years, how it is impacting my GC? If there is any negative impact how can I minimize it?

Answer (score 2):

For EB3, the experience/education requirements are similar to H1b, so if you got the H1b visa - there will probably not be an issue for GC as well. Even for EB2, 8 documented years of experience is more than enough, if you have a 4-year degree.